# Accuracy of Data Mining on Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, data-mining, oracle19c

I am a complete beginner at data mining with Oracle SQL

I have got a set of data with several attributes a `target` to investigate
There are more than 100,000 records

```
user_id
target
attribute_1
attribute_2
...
attribute_60
```

I create my `build`, `test` and `apply` views, then I create a `model` based on `data mining classification`

Finally I run an accuracy check and get only 80% of `accuracy`

```
SELECT SUM(accurate) / COUNT(*) AS accuracy
FROM(
  SELECT DECODE(target, PREDICTION(model USING *), 1, 0) AS accurate
  FROM test_view
);
```

I wanted to rise the `accuracy` to at least 90%, for that I gathered the `explanatory value` of each attribute and kept only the best ones in my views.
But this resulted in a lower accuracy... I think that's because Oracle API already prepares the data automatically, so maybe it was an unnecessary step.

I tried other algorythms, other ways to measure the results such as precision, recall, etc., but I find myself stuck.

I don't have much control over the data, I am just using what's available.
Is there a way I can improve the accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

In your query your accuracy will depend upon the value of the column target.I think you need to modify the query as below to get the correct mining results

```
SELECT SUM(accurate) / COUNT(*) AS accuracy
FROM(
 SELECT DECODE(PREDICTION(model USING *),1, 1, 0) AS accurate
 FROM test_view
);
```